# Populating a defaultdict at init time

Tags: python, list-comprehension, defaultdict, generator-expression

How can I get a callable factory for a defaultdict to allow populating it with a comprehension?  I think it's probably not possible, but I can't think of a good reason why?

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...     # TODO
...
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> thing = foo(defaultdict, int)
>>> d = thing((i, i*i) for i in range(3))
>>> d[2]
# should return 4
>>> d[-1]
# should return 0
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What are `thing` and `foo` and why should `thing` return 0?

Comment: To clarify: `thing((i, i*i) for i in range(3))` should return a `defaultdict` instance.  I will edit the question to make that clearer

Comment: Oh ok, the `-1` made me think it was a list rather than a missing index. If you wanted a `default_factory` that would do this, I don't think it could be done, because (from the docs) "The default factory is called ***without arguments*** to produce a new value when a key is not present, in __getitem__ only."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any arguments to `defaultdict` after the `default_factory` are treated just like arguments to `dict`:

```
>>> defaultdict(int, [(i, i*i) for i in range(5)])
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16})
```

Just pass the comprehension to `defaultdict` and let it do the work:

```
def defaultdict_factory_factory(default_factory):
    def defaultdict_factory(*args, **kwargs):
        return defaultdict(default_factory, *args, **kwargs)
    return defaultdict_factory
```

Or use `functools.partial`:

```
def defaultdict_factory_factory(default_factory):
    return partial(defaultdict, default_factory)
```

Comment: Very nice! This is noted in the docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) but not in `help(defaultdict)` (at least in my Python 2.7 install)

Comment: Yep surprisingly missing from the docstring of defaultdict.  I wonder how many other little python secrets are hiding out there ...

Comment: If this is still missing from the docstring in 3.4b2, someone should submit a bug report. (I'm assuming `defaultdict` is being affected by the argument clinic derby, so you can't just check the latest 3.3 release.)

Comment: It's still missing in the latest trunk, so I filed http://bugs.python.org/issue20250

Comment: As a side note, the OP is using a genexpr, which you've converted to a listcomp, and there's no obvious reason to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Are you just looking for `defaultdict.update`?

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> thing = defaultdict(int)
>>> thing.update((i, i*i) for i in range(3))
>>> thing
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4})
```

You could put this into a function.

```
>>> def initdefaultdict(type_, *args, **kwargs):
...     d = defaultdict(type_)
...     d.update(*args, **kwargs)
...     return d
... 
>>> thing = initdefaultdict(int, ((i, i+10) for i in range(3)))
>>> thing
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12})
>>> thing[3]
0
```

Or to satisfy your original requirements, return a function:

```
>>> def defaultdictinitfactory(type_): # this is your "foo"
...     def createupdate(*args, **kwargs):
...             d = defaultdict(type_)
...             d.update(*args, **kwargs)
...             return d
...     return createupdate
... 
>>> f = defaultdictinitfactory(int) # f is your "thing"
>>> d = f((i, i*i) for i in range(3))
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4})
>>>
```